# How to get value of textbox to Xtrareport

Tags: c#, wpf, xtrareport

I have `textbox` in `MainWindow.xaml`. So, i want to get value of this textbox to a `XRlabel` of `Xtrareport` form. How to do this? Thanks!!!

Comment: please read this on how to ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [XtraReport.FindControl](https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XRControl.FindControl.method) or [XtraReport.AllControls](https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XRControl.AllControls~T~.method) method to find that label in a report and assign its `XRLabel.Text` property value before showing its preview.

Another way is to use report parameters [like this](https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/10000/Detailed-Guide-to-DevExpress-Reporting/Shaping-Report-Data/Using-Report-Parameters/Requesting-and-Passing-Report-Parameter-Values#Runtime) and bind `XRLabel` to a parameter, so that you need to pass a value from `TextBox` to a report parameter.